# Copy a column from one table into another table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have tried this with `ALTER TABLE` to create the column followed by `INSERT INTO`. This kind of works, except each subsequent column starts after the previous column has ended. I guess this is how insert into works, so is there a workaround or another query I can build?

I have been trying with updates but its not working out.
For reference, these were the alter/insert queries i used.

```vb
SQL = "ALTER TABLE [results] ADD COLUMN [" & fld.Name & "_result] TEXT(25)"
db.Execute SQL
SQL = "INSERT INTO [results] ([" & fld.Name & "_result]) SELECT [Result] As 
    [" & fld.Name & "_result] FROM [newtable]"
db.Execute SQL
```

Comment: [Should I put tags in my question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). No you should not.

Comment: What's the real problem? (You're describing a "solution" that doesn't work. You should describe the real problem instead.)

Comment: I mentioned that.. the data in the columns that get added start after the previous columns has ended. I want them all to start at the top

Comment: Are there any other columns present in [results] and [newtable]?

Comment: newtable has other columns, result table has none initially and is in a loop that will add more as the loop goes on

Comment: "each subsequent column starts after the previous column has ended": what does that mean exactly? I'm having problems envisioning what it's doing based on your description. Is it that new rows are getting added and you want to update the available rows instead?

Comment: What's the structure of the two tables *AT* the time you're executing the insert into statement? If the new results are not getting added at the top then that means the results table already had some data in it.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal At first the result table is completely empty. (No columns, no rows). At each iteration of the for loop, the two queries are run which add 1 column.

Comment: I think when the loop ends you want results to be just like your newtable.. correct?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal on each loop, the result column of newtable changes and I want it to copy that column to a new column in results. So at the end results will have each change newtable went through.

Comment: Do you have a primary key for newtable? What's that column's name?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal the column i want to copy is named "Result"

Comment: I know that but I need to identify every "Result" row in newtable uniquely. So, can you help me help you here?

Answer (score 1):

Your insert statement assumes that the results table has only one column that you need to insert data into.  This is unlikely to be true, if the table already had other columns before you executed the ADD COLUMN.

You will need to keep track of the columns in the results table, and provide data (or a default value) for each column.

It is rather unusual to expand a table's structure from inside an application.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you sure you can't accomplish it better by defining fixed tables and then adding data from your application?

UPDATE

Okay, I think I understand what you're describing.  On the first iteration, the ALTER TABLE creates the first column.  The INSERT adds a bunch of rows that have data in this first column.

On the second interation, the ALTER TABLE creates a second column.  The INSERT creates a whole bunch of new rows, but only the second column is populated.  The first column is all NULL because you didn't provide values for it.  And so on and so forth for the third and subsequent iterations.

If your actual intention is to duplicate the source table and its data, then you should create your results table in a single pass.  You know the column structure, right?  Use a CREATE TABLE statement.  Then write a single INSERT statement somewhat like the following:

```
INSERT INTO [results] 
([field1_result], [field2_result], [field3_result]) 
SELECT [Result] As 
[field1_result, [field2_result], [field3_result]] 
FROM [newtable]
```

Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: So I should add all the columns first, and then put the data into those columns?

Comment: Usually people create the table with all of its columns first. Then, when the application runs, it manipulates data in the table using SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operations. That typically adds rows, not columns.  The application doesn't usually create columns on the fly. But it depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: That wouldn't work for me since there is only 1 result field in newtable that gets constantly updated. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

Before you enter into the loop create your `[results]` table as

```
SQL = "CREATE TABLE [results] SELECT [primary_key] FROM [newtable]"
db.Execute SQL
```

Then at every iteration of the loop execute

```
SQL = "ALTER TABLE [results] ADD COLUMN [" & fld.Name & "_result] TEXT(25)"
db.Execute SQL

SQL = "UPDATE [results] SET r.[" & fld.Name & "_result] = n.[Result] " & 
      "FROM [results] r, [newtable] n " &
      "WHERE r.[primary_key] = n.[primary_key]"
db.Execute SQL
```

So, if you had your `[newtable]` at its first two iterations like

```
[primary_key] [Results]    [primary_key] [Results]
     1           A              1           D
     2           B              2           E
     3           C              3           F
```

Your `[results]` table (after the above two iterations) would look like

```
[primary_key] [fld1_result] [fld2_result]
     1             A             D
     2             B             E
     3             C             F
```

Comment: Sick dude. That looks like it should work, but it gives me a syntax error (missing operator) on `n.[Result] FROM [results] r` for some reason?

Comment: Alright. I had to do Update-Inner Join-Set because yours didn't work for some reason. Also for access it is SELECT.. INTO.. FROM instead of Create Table As.. You did set me on the right path so TYVM! Also I didn't know you could do the renaming thing in queries. Thats pretty awesome.